# access 64bit dll from 32bit process using C++

Tags: c++, com, ipc, 32bit-64bit

I do release that its not possible to load 64bit dll into 32bit dll in the same process.
However i can put my 64bit dll into com and access that com from my 32bit app.
Can anyone provide me a sample for doing so? Are there any other means to solve this issue?

Note: I cannot build the 64bit dll to 32 bit as its external 3rd party dll and i cannot convert my 32bit process to 64 bit as its a very huge application.Converting that to 64bit would require me many years.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can use COM exe server or any other way of inter-process communications (sockets, pipes, global events, shared memory, Windows messaging etc.). Decide which way is better for you.

Comment: Where can i find an example of doing so using COM exe server?

Comment: search for "out-of-process" COM server. You can also use DCOM. I heard it's possible to use `dllhost.exe` (comes with Windows) to turn an in-process COM server into a DCOM server although I'm not srue about the details

Comment: Does the COM server contain a type library or is it accompanied with one?

Comment: @MattMcNabb you heard correctly; its called a [**DLL Surrogate**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695225(v=vs.85).aspx), and if your component is conforming (it doesn't take much) you can do this. I've done it the other way around (64-bit process hitting up a 32-bit surrogate-hosted in-proc-COM-lib) and can testify it can be done.

Comment: Can anyone provide me with sample or example of how to do this?

Comment: @user3462791: Whether you can do this depends on whether there's a type library with the COM server.

Comment: @sharptooth : i havent created a COM server yet. i just have 64bit dll with me..I should create a COM server and call this dll in this server. Which means i should also create a type library along with that. So i wanted to know a sample to do this

Comment: @user3462791: Oh, great, you can start with "ATL Project" template in Visual Studio - that will create a COM dll project with an IDL. In IDL you define your interface and you'd better make it Automation-compatible so that you don't need the proxy-stubs.

Answer (score 1):

you can leverage process communication about access 64bit from 32bit Process.
Below are some steps.

1. Make a COM server, [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8679/Building-a-LOCAL-COM-Server-and-Client-A-Step-by-S), you can modify project property to generate 64bit program.
2. Define and implement com `interface`, in COM server, you load 64bit dll, and wrapper dll function.
3. 32bit App call COM server interface([CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_64_BIT_SERVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693716%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)), send data by parameter and get result.